# How to sum values in rows in a table in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

i have a table of different prices in each rows. how do i make a sum of those rows in google docs and display it with "sum="?

Unit Name   Description        Price
<>   <>   <>
<>   <>   <>

sum=

Comment: I think you just need to type = and then "sum" :-)

Comment: Thank you for the response. But how to use the "sum". I'm fairly new to this. The doc is connected to a third party extension that takes in values from a Google Form and puts them into the doc. therefore, the values change and every time a form is submitted a new google doc is created with all the new values. How do I show the sum in the doc then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [script](http://gregoryzynda.com/webdev/google/docs/script/2014/06/09/google-apps-script.html) and tested it.

```
function sumTable() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var body = doc.getBody();

  var tables = body.getTables();
    var numRows = tables[0].getNumRows();//specify the table in [ ] that you're working with

  var row;
    var val;
  var total = 0.0;
    for(row = 1; row<numRows-1; row++) {
        val = tables[0].getCell(row, 2).getText();
       
    if(val) {
        total += parseFloat(val);
        }
  }

  tables[0].getCell(numRows -1,2).setText("$"+total.toString());
}
```

Now when you click “Run” in your Apps Script project it will execute and update the table, if you want to run the script from the Google Doc, you can run this other function and it will add an option under “Add-ons” from the Google Doc menu.

```
function onOpen(e) {
    var menu = DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
    menu.addItem("Sum Table", "sumTable");
    menu.addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. Any idea how to do it through AppsScripts, please?

Comment: @gg0wwrr1 the answer has been updated with the information you last requested